# LWJGL OpenGL - Line from 3d point to center of screen

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Is there is an easy way to draw a line from a 3D point, in this case, it's 0, 0, 0, to the center of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [gluUnProject](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/glu/Project.html) to figure out the 3D coordinates of the screen center (at a given depth), then draw a line between two 3D points.